# CodeIgniter , how to get single element instead of array of size 1?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm new to CodeIgniter. I love it, it's great, but one issue cannot resolve for days.

I'm trying to get a single row, by its id, like this :

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('content', ['id' => $id]);
$the_content = $query->result_array();
```

However, it results in an array of size 1, like this:

```
$the_content = [ 0 => ['id' => 1, 'content'=> 'abc']];
```

so I always have to convert it to its first element like this:

```
$the_content= $the_content[0];
```

But you can understand why I don't like this.

I also tried `$query->result();` , still the same.

I'm sure I'm missing a simple point here, but what?

How do I get single element from ActiveRecord instead of array?

Comment: **$query = $this->db->get_where('content', ['id' => $id]);  
$the_content = $query->row();**

Answer (score 3):

The solution would be:

```
$the_content = $query->row_array();
```

To return a single dimentional array. To retrieve you would write:

```
echo $the_content['content'];
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`first_row()`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html):

```
$row = $query->first_row();
```

If you want an array instead:

```
$row = $query->first_row('array')
```

Or if you want a specific row returned you can submit the row number as a digit in the first parameter:

```
$row = $query->row_array(3);
```

If you want to get the field of the first row:

```
$field = $query->first_row()->field;
echo $field;
```

See the documentation [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html).

Comment: I up voted this because it was the first answer, it was well thought out and very thorough. It leaves with no questions but just in case sends you the documentation link. Kudos

Answer (score 1):

There is a function to get the first row from query:

```
$the_content = $query->first_row('array')
```

ref: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html